# django project derived from python-socketio django example unable to server other URLs (at least in django 1.11)

Tags: django, authentication, django-1.11, python-socketio

After playing with `python-socketio`s django_example, and seeing that it worked great, I created a new django project, configured it just like the example, copied over the example app to the project (complete with it's overriding of the runserver management command).  Everything worked fine, and I was able to make my a few changes so that you can set a *nick*, some redis stuff to lookup up the sid for a nick, and was able to support sending private messages to a nick. Everything was still working great.

I figured the next logical step was to, rather than having to manually set a nick, require the user to login, expose their username as a var in a script block in the template (I moved `scripts/index.html` to `templates/index.html`), and automatically have the javascript emit my custom 'set_nick' event with the username automatically upon connect.

I defined `LOGIN_URL = '/accounts/login'` in **settings.py**, included  'django.contrib.auth.urls' in my **urls.py** and wrapped the index view with `@login_required`.

It was only then that I noticed that no matter what URL you request, you always get the chat apps index view - no login page redirect, '/admin/' is ignored, etc.

**EDIT** Solved - See my answer below.

Comment: are you sure that you are not already logged in? can you check the site via incognito mode?

Comment: @ruddra hmm. you're right.  Also, one odd thing with the socketio-enhanced runserver command is that it doesn't seem to auto-detect/reload changes to server code, and you need to ctrl-C it twice to totally kill it.  now it looks like I simply need to fix a broken login.html template

Comment: Please move your solution to an answer of its own, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I noticed that the `urls.py` which I blindly copied over from the example looked like this:

```
url(r'', include('socketio_app.urls')),
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

and the `r''` was the culprit (matches everthing). Changing this to:

```
url(r'^/', include('socketio_app.urls)),
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
```

However, I'm using Django==1.11.  I *believe* Django 2 tends to suggest using `path` (or some similarly named function) rather than using `url`. I **don't** believe, however, that the semantics of `url` are different in Django 2, so this is *probably* an issue for Django 2 users as well.